# Can I send a envelope via the DocUSign UI and then open and sign that envelope/contract via my app?

Tags: docusignapi

The marketing team want to send out an envelope via the UI.

The recipient of that envelope will go onto our marketing site and then sign and view the contract.

Because the below request does not include a clientUserId I then cannot call the Recipient View API to get a URL to then display the envelope/contract.

```
// call to get recipients
export const getRecipient = async (envelopeId: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${process.env.DOCUSIGN_BASE_URI}accounts/${process.env.DOCUSIGN_API_ACCOUNT_ID}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/recipients`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: config().headers,
      }
    );

    const { signers } = await response.json();
    return signers;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error checking envelope status:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

```
// call to create recipient view
export const createRecipientView = async ({
  envelopeId,
  accountId,
  returnUrl,
  userName,
  userEmail,
  clientUserId,
}: RecipientViewRequest): Promise<{ url: string }> => {
  const requestData = {
    returnUrl,
    authenticationMethod: "None",
    email: userEmail,
    userName,
    clientUserId,
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${process.env.DOCUSIGN_BASE_URI}accounts/${accountId}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/views/recipient`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: config().headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        next: { revalidate: 3600 },
      }
    );
    const { url } = await response.json();

    return url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating recipient view:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Have I missed something and is it possible to send a envelope via the DocUSign UI and then open and sign that envelope/contract via my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first modify the envelope with another API call (first lock it, this initiates "Correct" then PUT to update the recipients) to add the **clientUserId** and then you can do embedded signing.

However, you have to own this envelope, if the marketing team is using a different account/user from the one your integration will be using to authenticate, then it won't work unless they also shared these envelopes with you.

[Blog post about how to correct an envelope from your code](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-correct-envelope-your-app)